# Null value in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate PDF report with Jasper Reports, when I preview the report  it worked but when I entered an id from a html page I had `null`, the picture below presents the result:

[image]

Here  my code:
index.html

```
 <form action="Print">
   <input type="text"  name="id" >
   <input type="submit"  value="print">
 </form>
```

Print.java

```
 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

 // set input and output stream
 ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();  
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 FileInputStream fis;
 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;

 try {          
     // get report location
     ServletContext context = getServletContext();
     String reportLocation = context.getRealPath("");

     // get report
     fis = new FileInputStream(reportLocation + "/newReport.jasper");
     bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     Map map=new HashMap();
     map.put("parameter1", id);
     // export to pdf           
     JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream);
     JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
       map, new JREmptyDataSource());
     JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);
     response.setContentLength(baos.size());
     baos.writeTo(servletOutputStream);

     // close it
     fis.close();
     bufferedInputStream.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally{
     servletOutputStream.flush();
     servletOutputStream.close();
     baos.close();
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the error console?

Comment: @mak_doni And what is your question?

Comment: @João Marcos  I didn't have any error in the GlassFich

Comment: @ Alex K I want to have the data in the report not a null value

Comment: @mak_doni What do you mean? You have to replace null with another value or what?

Comment: Thanks for all, I forget to connect with the database and now it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Map

```
map.put("parameter1", id);
```

is correctly defined!

Probably you have a problem in your key named "parameter1".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I forget to connect with the database and now it works very well.

Comment: if i help u please approve my answer. tks a lot